# Add Custom Domain in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, dns, azure-blob-storage, static-site, custom-domain

Error creating Custom Domain in Azure

Hi, I am trying to link a custom domain to my static website that is located on my blob storage account. When creating the custom domain these are the azure instructions "Create a CNAME record with the DNS provider that points the domain (eg, www.contoso.com) to blobstorage.blob.core.windows.net or blobstorage.z13 .web.core.windows.net and then specify your domain. This method is simpler, but causes a short downtime while Azure checks the domain registration. "

In my godaddy account I have created a new CNAME record as follows Type: CNAME, name: www.mydomain.com, value: blobstorage.z13.web.core.windows.net.Y when trying to specify the custom domain in azure (mydomain.com) generates the following error: "Could not update storage account 'XXXX'. Error: The custom domain name could not be verified. CNAME mapping from mydomain.com to any of ..... does not exist "

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, I am very new in the subject and I really appreciate the help you can give me. Thank you very much

Comment: Edited the question and included the English translation.

Comment: One problem with DNS is that it can take time for the change to be seen by Azure. Try again and see if it works.

Comment: If you want to add custom domain to Azure storage, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name.

Comment: your CNAME mapping is incorrect. You need to add a CNAME entry as  NAME: "www.midominio.com" ,  Value:  "blobstorage.z13.web.core.windows.net".

Comment: verify your CNAME mapping here: https://manytools.org/network/query-dns-records-online/

Comment: I 
I read the information and it tells me to create a new cname record in my dns provider. I did it in godaddy as I indicated in the question Type: CNAME, name: www.mydomain.com, value: blobstorage.z13.web.core.windows.net but when trying to specify after that the domain in azure doesn't work for me and generates the error specified in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could already make the configuration I was looking for by configuring a CDN. this is the link learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/… Thanks everybody fot your answers and comments –

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have the CNAME record set correctly in the DNS settings for your domain name, then give it some time to update. DNS doesn't update immediately, it can take some time for the update to sync through all the DNS server between your registrar and Azure or your local ISP. This is especially the case when you test and it fails, then you need to wait at minimum the TTL (time-to-live) time that is set on the DNS records updated before you'll be able to test again.

On an aside, I'd recommend setting the TTL on the DNS records to 1/2 hour, then when everything's working you can go update it to a longer TTL. This will help when you need to update things and retest again to get it working.

Comment: I could already make the configuration I was looking for by configuring a CDN. this is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-custom-domain Thanks everybody fot your answers and comments